# Share data between component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is extending form like:

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./common/form";
import AppFeature from "./common/appFeature";
class AddFeature extends Form {
render() {
<AppFeature role={"newRole"} />}
}
```

When I tried to get the role value in `appfeature` component through `this.props.role`. I'll get `undefined`.

Any workaround for this???

Comment: You are just passing a string for your prop value. Can you give a little bit more context, maybe a sandbox?

Comment: @barteezy i'm passing a string only but in place of extending component i have extended the `Form`.

Comment: If it's relevant, also show us that code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-field-jp4b0?fontsize=14

Comment: I think the problem is with your `doSubmit `function. On your `form`component you are calling it with `this.doSubmit`but it is not defined on the form component.

Comment: @barteezy it is there in `addRole.jsx`

Comment: Sorry I missed it, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You're `doSubmit` function is not correct.

You need to update state - `showFeatures` to `true` to render `AddFeature` component.

You are calling `history.push` to a specific route which is not defined and uses `React Router` to do that.

Use below code and you will be able to get props to `AddFeature` component

```
  doSubmit = async ex => {
    try {
      this.setState({
        showFeatures: true
      })
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex.response);
    }
  };
```